# How to download data for my package on demand?

Tags: r, download, package

I am the author of an R package that implements file loaders and ships example files which are used in unit tests and in the examples, e.g., if you run `example(func_from_mypackage)` in GNU R.

I was asked by CRAN people to "download package data on demand" and host it on some external server, as it is exceeds the 5 MB package size limit.
Is there any standard way to do this?

My idea so far: I could make a function `dl_data_if_not_available()` and call it as the first thing in every example. But where to should I download the data? E.g., would it be acceptable to download to something like `$HOME/.mypackage/data/`?

I would prefer that the data could be accessed like package data, e.g.:

```r
some_file = system.file("extdata", "some_file.dta", package = "mypackage", mustWork = TRUE);
```

But is there any way to *download* to that location (the package data dir of my package)?

EDIT: To make it clear: I do **not** want the user to have to download the data each time to a temporary location. I want the data to be downloaded once, and then be stored. The data are needed often, and they do not change.

UPDATE: I found a package BiocFileCache for BioConductor, and it seems to do what I would need -- but for bioconductor, not for CRAN. I did not find something similar for CRAN yet. Maybe I will just delete my package on CRAN and move to bioconductor, or leave both and ask people to `devtools::install_github()` my package instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found nothing and ended up writing my own package to do this. It's nothing too fancy, but it does the trick and I made it available in case anybody else wants it: [pkgfilecache package on CRAN](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=pkgfilecache), [pkgfilecache code on github](https://github.com/dfsp-spirit/pkgfilecache)

Answer (score 0):

If it must not be included in the package and later used with a `data()` call, then maybe the appropriate place to download the data to might be to the location specified with `temp()`.

This points to the temporary folder of the current R session and will be deleted together with the session.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But this would mean that the data gets re-downloaded *every time* the package is used in a new session, if I understand correctly. Or at least every time the user runs an `example()` in a new session. That is not acceptable.